# use highlight.js theme in rmarkdown::html_document() .Rmd

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

Can I specify a `highlight.js` style in RMarkdown front matter when using html_document?

#### example:

Instead of using `pandoc`'s `espresso` highlighting say I want `highlight.js`'s `tommorrow` highlithing which lives [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/7.3/styles/tomorrow.min.css)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    highlight: espresso
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

etc...
````

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not built-in way to do this but you can add the following lines at the beginning of your `Rmd` document to get what you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import "https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/styles/tomorrow.css";
</style>
```